# How to generate random IP addresses

Tags: shell, ip, random, nmap

```
$ nmap -n -iR 0 -sL > RANDOM-IPS-TMP.txt
$ grep -o "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*" RANDOM-IPS-TMP.txt |
      egrep -v "10.*|172.[16-32].*|192.168.*|[224-255].*" > RANDOM-IPS.txt
egrep: Invalid range end
$
```

How can I generate random IP Addresses outside the private IP address range and the multicast IP Address range?

Comment: I am afraid to ask why someone wants to generate random ips that feed into nmap.

Comment: @Mike: Actually `nmap` is being used to generate those random IP's, not the other way around. But I too am afraid to ask what they are getting fed INTO! Maybe it's a grand hunt for [https only](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14663/1925) servers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You misunderstand regex syntax.  `[16-32]` does not mean "match 16, 17, ... or 32".  It means "match one character which is either 1 or 2 or in the range 6-3" (which is not a valid range, hence the error).

It's possible to write a regex to match a range of integers, but it's complex and error prone.  In your case, it would be much easier to use `nmap`'s [`--exclude` option](http://nmap.org/book/man-target-specification.html) to exclude the ranges you don't want.  It understands CIDR notation, which is a much simpler way to describe the ranges you're talking about.

```
nmap -n -iR 0 --exclude 10.0.0.0/8,172.16.0.0/12,192.168.0.0/16,224-255.-.-.- -sL >RANDOM-IPS.txt
```

You didn't mention the loopback block (127.0.0.0/8), but you probably ought to exclude that too.

Comment: Note to everyone that it's really important to leave the -sL and -n options in place on this, otherwise you're going to scan the internet and may get in trouble for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

This shell snippet generates an IP address.

```
ip_address=$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=4 count=1 2>/dev/null |
             od -An -tu1 |
             sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/  */./g')
```

If you're not happy with it, try again in a loop.

```
while
  set $(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=4 count=1 2>/dev/null | od -An -tu1)
  [ $1 -lt 224 ] &&
  [ $1 -ne 10 ] &&
  { [ $1 -ne 192 ] || [ $2 -ne 168 ]; } &&
  { [ $1 -ne 172 ] || [ $2 -lt 16 ] || [ $2 -gt 31 ]; }
do :; done
ip_address=$1.$2.$3.$4
```