# Fake IP addresses generator

Tags: ssh, ip, testing

I have an application running on a server that adds a new iptable rule blocking every IP address trying to connect via SSH with a wrong password. Now, I'd like to perform a stress test where many (fake) IP addresses try to connect.

Is there anything out there to do such thing? I.e., use a range of fake IPs from a single host to try to connect to a server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate random IP addresses](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14666/how-to-generate-random-ip-addresses)

Comment: Please read the questions, this is not a duplicate of the linked question. The linked question is about generating IPs, this question wants to generate traffic from the IPs.

Comment: This isn't directly related, but have you thought about the side effects of blocking IPs on password fail? Or will this be after 3+ password fails? For a more direct answer, I can't be sure, but would it work to create a script to add many randomly generated IPs to iptables block list, it wouldn't work with testing the SSH side of the script, but it would test the stress on iptables.

Comment: There seems to be disagreement about what the question is about, can you clarify.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up another machine as the default router for your server and use that machine to generate the appropriate traffic, maybe?

Comment: this should be a comment...

Comment: I had too low rep to post comment when I posted this...

Answer (score 0):

it is very easy to spoof ip addresses for just sending one packet (DoS Attacks) but in your case you need a working TCP Session.

So when you start with your first IP Test the SSH Server will answer the `TCP Syn` packet with a `TCP ACK` packet and the Testing Host will reply with a `TCP SYN Ack`. After that the SSH Connection wil be up (TCP three-way handshake). After that SSH Auth an so on will be processed. So for an easy way of testing the two Hosts should be in the same IP Subnet.

Have a look at dsniff: http://sectools.org/tool/dsniff/

I would also try to write a script and use IP alias addresses on my networkcard